# как обратиться к элементу словаря по ключу?

Tags: c#

как обратиться к элементу словаря по ключу, если ключ -

```
List<string>?
```

извиняюсь за неполное описание. 
мне нужно не просто получить значение, а увеличить его на 1.

Comment: List - это не словарь, а список

Comment: Не следует использовать `List<T>` в качестве ключа хэш-таблицы - у него не переопределен GetHashCode.

Answer (score 3):

1. Просто по "индексу", с обработкой исключения `KeyNotFoundException`

```
try {
    Console.WriteLine("Значение = {0}.", dict[key]);
} catch (KeyNotFoundException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Ключ не найден.");
}
```

2. Метод `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue (TKey, TValue)`
   [msdn: TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Значение = {0}.", value);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Ключ не найден.");
}
```

3. Проверить предварительно наличие ключа
   [msdn: ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) {
  Console.WriteLine("Значение = {0}.", dict[key]);
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("Ключ не найден.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом `Dictionary.TryGetValue()`

```
var myValue;
List<string> key;
if (MyDict.TryGetValue(key, out myValue)) 
 { /* use myValue */ }
```